# Glassfish 2.1.1 domain crash while deploying jbi service if heap size is 2 GB

Tags: jvm, glassfish, dns

i have glassfish 2.1.1 running on top of 32 bit RHEL 4 where i need to frequently deploy and undeploy around 30-40 jbi service assemblies packaged in zip files. I use a shell script where the "asadmin deploy-jbi-service-assembly" and "asadmin start-jbi-service-assembly" commands run inside a loop. A peculiar thing I have encountered is that when I set the heap size of the domains through Xmx jvm option to 2048m, undeployment goes fine, but during deployment, after around 6-7 deployments, the domain crashes. When I reduced the heap size from 2048m to around 1700m, I was able to deploy all assemblies without hiccup. But then after deployment I again have to change the heap size and restart the domains. The server has about 48GB memory with 2 quad core cpus, so resource isn't scarce. This is getting to be a real headache. Anyone help me out ????